# Solving sliding puzzle in Python with a* algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to develop a sliding puzzle solver using a* algorithm. However, I am unable to comprehend what is wrong with my code, because though it does work, it works painfully slow, so I came down to conclusion what either my input is complex for algorithm or I've coded it poorly. Here's my code:

```
initialMatrix = [[5, 3, 4],
                 [6, 0, 7],
                 [8, 2, 1]]

goalMatrix = [[1, 2, 3],
              [8, 0, 4],
              [7, 6, 5]]

Checked = []
Unchecked = []

parent = {}
f = {}
g = {}
h = {}

neighbours = []
step = 0

Unchecked.append(initialMatrix)
parent[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)] = None
g[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)] = 0
h[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)] = calculateMisplacedTiles(initialMatrix, goalMatrix)
f[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)] = g[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)] + h[MatrixToString(initialMatrix)]

while len(Unchecked) != 0:
    current = findMatrixWithMinWeight(Unchecked, f)
    step += 1

    if current == goalMatrix:
        break

    Unchecked.remove(current)
    Checked.append(current)

    emptyPos = findEmpty(current)
    if emptyPos[0] > 0:
        neighbours.append(UpRule(current, emptyPos))
        h[MatrixToString(neighbours[-1])] = calculateMisplacedTiles(neighbours[-1], goalMatrix)
    if emptyPos[0] < 2:
        neighbours.append(DownRule(current, emptyPos))
        h[MatrixToString(neighbours[-1])] = calculateMisplacedTiles(neighbours[-1], goalMatrix)
    if emptyPos[1] > 0:
        neighbours.append(LeftRule(current, emptyPos))
        h[MatrixToString(neighbours[-1])] = calculateMisplacedTiles(neighbours[-1], goalMatrix)
    if emptyPos[1] < 2:
        neighbours.append(RightRule(current, emptyPos))
        h[MatrixToString(neighbours[-1])] = calculateMisplacedTiles(neighbours[-1], goalMatrix)

    for neighbour in neighbours:
        tentativeScore = g[MatrixToString(current)] + 1
        if neighbour in Checked and tentativeScore >= g[MatrixToString(neighbour)]:
            continue
        if neighbour not in Checked or tentativeScore < g[MatrixToString(neighbour)]:
            parent[MatrixToString(neighbour)] = current
            g[MatrixToString(neighbour)] = tentativeScore
            f[MatrixToString(neighbour)] = g[MatrixToString(neighbour)] + h[MatrixToString(neighbour)]
            if neighbour not in Unchecked:
                Unchecked.append(neighbour)
    neighbours.clear()
```

All functions not shown here are working properly, at least I wasn't able to find any problem in them.
Edit: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough, but when I said about slow speed, first of all, I meant the number of steps taken for algorithm to reach the conclusion. Although the time of execution is horrible too.

Comment: `neighbour in Checked` could be slow because Checked is a list instead of a set - lookup in a list is O(n) time

Comment: `Unchecked.remove(current)` is likely to be somewhat slow, and while you don't show the implementation, I'd guess that `findMatrixWithMinWeight` is going to be slow too. Hash tables (e.g. `set`s) and heaps (e.g. using the `heapq` module) can make things a lot better.